# Can I use a span tag outside a p?

Tags: html, tags

I was placing some icon fonts inside a link and then i asked myself:
is semantically correct to use a `span` tag outside a `p` one?

In example

```
<a href="http://fb.com">
    <span class="my-icon-font">link</span>
</a>
```

Comment: ... yes it is. Div ex: `<div><span>stuff</span></div>`

Comment: Yes. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element

Comment: You can always use [online validator](http://validator.w3.org) to check you html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a semantic perspective, a `span` really doesn't mean much. It's just a marker for some inline content.

From a technical perspective, a `span` can go anywhere that you have an `inline` display context, which basically means anywhere at all (since HTML allows you to have inline elements in the same context as block elements).

It certainly isn't limited to being inside a `p` tag. It can go pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **NO**

You can read these two section

[**span** element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element)

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>       Where **phrasing** content is expected.

[**p** element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>       Where flow content is expected.
>
> Content model:
>       Phrasing content.

A `span` just allows **phrasing** content element inside it while a `p` is an **flow** content element. However, a `p` can contains a `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; there is nothing wrong with that.

However, you might as well move the `class` to the `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's nothing wrong with that. As long as you don't do this:

```
<a href="http://fb.com">
    <span class="my-icon-font">link
</a></span>
```

And, since your  tag covers the whole same text as your  does, it is better to add the class to the  tag:

```
<a href="http://fb.com" class="my-icon-font">
    link
</a>
```

Comment: I disagree - he may have more `<span>` tags within the link in which case styling of those would be appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Would make sense to use where, for example, you might want to emphasize the text of more than one paragraph in sequence.  Otherwise, I would just use a class inside my

tag to emphasize the text.